# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux Unsupported architecture (arm) with Node.js 8.x

Tags: node.js, sass, arm, beagleboneblack, node-sass

When I run my reactJS application on beaglebone, I get an error  on arm with node-sass.

[image]

More information about my Beaglebone :

```
$uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.14.52-ti-r60 #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 26 22:50:05 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Versions :

```
 $node --version
 v8.11.2
 $npm --v
 6.1.0
```

Even using this command `npm rebuild node-sass` is not changing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions for rebuilding node-sass are found in the [Github repository's readme](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#rebuilding-binaries):

> Node-sass includes pre-compiled binaries for popular platforms, to add
>   a binary for your platform follow these steps

Comment: Thank you @TBR,  when I run my application on Beaglebone, I get : `This probably means the system ran out of memory` have you a solution please ?

Comment: As a workaround, you could enable 'swap'. It's going to be quite slow, but should work. Either create a new partition or swap to file. You will need enough storage space for this though, so a SD card will probably be required.

Comment: How to create a swap with SD card ?

Comment: Are you booting from eMMC or from SD-card? What size of card? What sort of debian image are you running?

Comment: My version is  :                                                            
debian@beaglebone:/etc$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"    And I  write the image to my on-board eMMC from SD card which have 4G

Comment: Please note which of the Debian images did you use? console? IoT? desktop? This is not evident from the above. Please also provide the output of `df -h /`

Comment: I use it on version IOT, and the output of `df -h / `is : `$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.5G  2.9G  438M  87% /`

Comment: Yeah, that's not enough free space to use as swap. Take a micro-SD that you can delete. a) Boot the device b) insert card c) `mkswap /dev/mmcblk0` (there might be a warning about overwriting things, that's fine) d) `swapon /dev/mmcblk0` e) verify using `cat /proc/meminfo |grep SwapTotal` - should say ~ size of SD

Comment: After that, I work with the SD card or can I remove it and work directly on the beaglebone?

Comment: The SD-card is then your extended Memory, you **MUST** keep it inserted while you compile the software that needs the large amount of memory. Notice that compiling will possibly take a very long time. Only after you have that done and installed you can reboot and remove the SD card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176963/discussion-between-codelover-and-tbr).